# MessageBox никак не хочет выводить русские символы

Tags: c++, winapi, devc++

Собственно, в заголовке проблема. Каждый раз иероглифы вместо русских букв. Пробовал всё, что находил в интернете, примерно 5-7 способов (такие как `L".."`, `TEXT("..")`, `_T("..")`, `reinterpret_cast<LPCTSTR>("...")` и вроде что-то ещё) - результат всегда один и тот же. 
Вызываю вот так:

```
MessageBox(NULL, "Привет!", "Здравствуй!", MB_OK);
```

Comment: А у вас Unicode-ная программа или нет? Это важно.

Comment: И исходники в какой кодировке?

Comment: @klopp Я точно не знаю и не нашёл, как узнать... Но на сайте http://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=ru вставил свой код из IDE и на сайте пишется, что у меня кодировка windows-1251. Но я не знаю, так ли это

Comment: @VladD не знаю, и не нашёл, как узнать :\

Comment: Правильный код должен быть с `L"Привет!"`. Если он не компилируется, то это проблема. А какой у вас системный язык, кстати?

Comment: Вот [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23427045/276994) советуют зайти в Project -> Project options -> Parameters и в поле "C++ compiler" добавить `-DUNICODE`.

Comment: @VladD, я уже видел этот совет, но, увы, у меня просто программа, отдельная, а не проект, поэтому всё, что связанно с проектом, неактивное. А L".." выдаёт ошибку - "converting to execution character set: Illegal byte sequence"

Comment: Странно. Я не знаю, почему так в вашей IDE. Может, надо просто остановить программу?

Comment: @VladD, в смысле программу остановить? Она же не запускается даже, если русские символы использую в L".."

Answer (score 5):

`MessageBox` - это макрос. В зависимости от специальных макроопределений для включения/выключения Unicode (`UNICODE` и `_UNICODE`)  он превращается либо в функцию `MessageBoxA` (A - ASCII), либо в функцию `MessageBoxW` (W - wide). `MessageBoxA` может выводить только ASCII-символы. Грубо говоря - только английский язык. `MessageBoxW` предназначен для вывода Unicode-символов, куда входят и символы кириллицы.

---

Первый вариант решения Вашей проблемы - прямо вызывать `MessageBoxW`. Туда нужно передавать строки с префиксом `L`, так как эта функция всегда принимает широкие строки и не меняет своего поведения.

```
MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Привет!", L"Здравствуй!", MB_OK);
```

---

Второй вариант - включить Unicode для проекта:

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

#ifndef _UNICODE
#define _UNICODE  
#endif

#include <Windows.h>
```

Обратите внимание, что `#include <Windows.h>` должен быть обязательно после #define'ов для Unicode. Так же, макроопределения можно, и лучше так и сделать, задавать в настройках проекта, в DevC++ это должно быть в *Project -> Project Options -> Parameters*, там в поле *C++ Compiler* нужно ввести`-DUNICODE` и `-D_UNICODE`.

При таком способе нужно использовать сам макрос `MessageBox` и передавать в него строки при помощи `_T()`.

```
MessageBox(NULL, _T("Привет!"), _T("Здравствуй!"), MB_OK);
```

При использовании `_T` программа будет работать вне зависимости от настроек Unicode. Под "работать" в данном случае я понимаю не "отображать русские символы", а "компилироваться и не падать при выводе `MessageBox`". Отображать русские символы она, само собой, будет только если Unicode включен.

Comment: при добавлении или define'ов про юникод, или в параметре компилятора про юникод (у меня не проект, а одиночная программа, поэтому нет параметров проекта, но параметры компилятора в целом есть), появляется ошибка >[Error] cannot convert 'const char*' to 'LPCWSTR {aka const wchar_t*}' for argument '2' to 'int MessageBoxW(HWND, LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR, UINT)'<, а при попытке дописать (LPCWSTR) к выводимым фразам запускается, но выдаёт чушь похуже, чем было :D Даже вместо английских символов таким способом выдаёт китайские иероглифы.

Comment: а L".." у меня никак не получается сделать с русскими символами - пишет [Error] converting to execution character set: Illegal byte sequence. Однако, всё работает нормально с английскими символами (и с L".." запускается)

Comment: Первая проблема: Вы пытаетесь скормить строки `char*` туда, куда нужны `wchar_t*`. Вы макрос `_T()` используете? Если нет, то попробуйте с ним.  Если да, то, возможно,  он нормально не определен, и можно попробовать [определить его самостоятельно](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22003804/3872804). По поводу второй проблемы, для борьбы с Illegal byte sequence можно попробовать указать `-finput-charset=iso-8859-1` или перекодировать файл исходного кода в UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы не морочить голову и разбираться с юникодом установи при запуске программы нужную локаль

где-то в начале

```
setlocale( LC_ALL, "ru_RU.UTF-8" );
```

или так

```
setlocale( LC_ALL, "ru_RU.cp1251" );
```

не забудь подключить `locale.h`

Но лучше использовать юникод и нормальную локализацию, а не вписывать текстовые строки в код.

Answer (score 0):

Еще одной неожиданной причиной по которой может не работать кириллица может быть то, что сам файл исходника в неправильной кодировке. Например если он создан изначально не в студии а в другом редакторе. Студия его может показывать нормально, но при запуске сторка

```
MessageBox(NULL, "Привет!", "Здравствуй!", MB_OK);
```

будет отображать нечитаемые символы

> "РџСЂРёРІРµС‚!", "Р—РґСЂР°РІСЃС‚РІСѓР№!"

Comment: это вообще не ответ.